# How would I go about testing how long it takes for the data to be downloaded for a JSON web service.

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

How would I go about testing how long it takes for the data to be downloaded from a JSON web service

Currently I'm the following code and would like to NSLog how long it takes to download.

```
- (void)downloadData{

// Download the JSON
NSString *jsonString = [NSString
                        stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:queryLine]
                        encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy|NSUTF8StringEncoding
                        error:nil];

NSMutableArray *itemsTMP = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Create parser for the api
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];

itemsTMP = [results objectForKey:@"results"];

[self setAllItems:[itemsTMP copy]];
self.displayItems = [itemsTMP copy];

int a =   [displayItems count];
    NSString *countString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" results %d",a];
    countLabel.text = countString;

}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Just a guess:  Download the data and time it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a "timestamp" before downloading the JSON

```
NSDate *startTime = [[NSDate alloc] init];

// Download the JSON
NSString *jsonString = [NSString
                        stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:queryLine]
                        encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy|NSUTF8StringEncoding
                        error:nil];

NSDate *elapsedTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:startTime];
```

elapsedTime is gonna be an NSDate object set to seconds seconds from date.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Instruments tool, available as part of the Apple Developer tools.  It's really great for doing exactly what you are asking, and for so many other things.  Here is a good place to start: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using. It worked great for my needs.

```
  NSLog(@"Begin <your method name>");
NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];

// Do something useful here

NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = [startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSLog(@"End <your method name>");
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Elapsed time: %f", -elapsedTime]);
```